# Rolling 2 dice with different sides against each other

Tags: probability

Geniuses!

We're having 2 dice with different sizes. For our example, dice A has 10 sides while dice B has 7 sides.
How to calculate the probability of Dice A being rolled higher than Dice B?

Thanks upfront!

Comment: There are $7 \cdot 10 = 70$ possible outcomes. Count the outcomes where dice A is larger than dice B, and divide by 70.

Comment: Consider counting outcomes of $\rm A$ that are *equal or lesser* than $\rm B$, which is the complement of the favored event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternative approach:

$$\frac{3}{10} + \left[\frac{7}{10} \times \frac{6}{7} \times \frac{1}{2}\right]. \tag1 $$

The 1st term above represents the probability of die A rolling $8$ or higher.  In the 2nd term above, you have the following $3$ factors:

- Die A rolling $7$ or lower
- Die A and Die B not matching
- $(1/2)$, which is motivated by symmetry.  At this point, it is equally likely that Die A is less than, rather than greater than Die B.

Comment: Perfect, exactly what i needed! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It may be useful to draw a table for questions like these and see the values where the ten sided die is larger than the seven. The first die has 7 outcomes and the second has 10 so multiplying together gives 70 possible outcomes. If the ten sided dice is a 1 then there is 0 outcomes, if the ten sided dice is a 2 then there is 1 outcome etc..., adding these together gives the possibilities, out of 70, for the ten sided to be larger.

Comment: Makes sense - thanks for pointing me into the the right direction!